# Return primary key for the inserted row (PHP adn SQLite)?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Get the specific primary key, just after inserting row into SQLite, using PHP.

I use PDO prepare-execute, and am not sure how to achieve this in simplest way.

Should I do a query just after inserting, something like:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM TableX 
WHERE Data = $data
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php?

Comment: Thats it, thanks. I thought I have to pass another querry to database. - Will you answer, so I can click your answer?